# PhpSpec Can not find appropriate suite scope for class error

Tags: php, bdd, phpspec

I am just starting out with PhpSpec.
When I do this:

`bin/phpspec desc src/CRMPicco/GolfBundle/Controller/CourseGuideController`

I get the following error:

```
  [PhpSpec\Exception\Locator\ResourceCreationException]
  Can not find appropriate suite scope for class `src/CRMPicco/GolfBundle/Controller/CourseGuideController`.
```

I created an empty `CourseGuideController` class in that directory so the class exists.

My `phpspec.yml`:

```
suites:
    CRMPiccoGolfBundle: { namespace: CRMPicco, spec_path: src/CRMPicco/GolfBundle }
```

`CourseGuideController.php`:

```
namespace CRMPicco\GolfBundle\Controller;

class CourseGuideController
{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:
    `bin/phpspec desc CRMPicco/GolfBundle/Controller/CourseGuideController`

Comment: I know this guy... ;)